Blocked:mixed-content problem when using docker containers
I have setup a docker server with a nginx proxy manager container as the front end exposed to the open internet. behind that I have a container with a flutter webapp and another container with a Python Flask API. named Webapp and API. the proxy manager sends traffic to the Webapp and proves SSL while keeping the API secure.
The webapp communicates with the API using post requests:
Future loginAuth(String username, String password) async {
    const String apiUrl = 'http://API:5000/login';
    Map<String, dynamic> requestBody = {
      'username': username,
      'password': password,
    };
    try {
      final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(apiUrl),
        headers: <String, String>{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        },
        body: jsonEncode(requestBody),
      );

all of this worked fine on my local computer, but when I pushed it to the server I got a Blocked:mixed-content when trying to access the API.
I have gone into the webapp container and done a curl to the API container, works fine. So they are on the same network. If I expose the API container to the outside I can access it. so both containers are working properly, the apps just won't talk to each other.
I think the problem is that the browser is communicating with the server with https then switching to HTTP to do the internal bit, and it doesn't like that. I have no idea how to fix it.
is there a way? or do I need to expose my API, give it an SSL cert and access it that way?
